# How to view all events belonging to some class?

Tags: visual-studio

I am using a Visual Studio 2012 Express. When I load some class, IDEs like IntelliJ IDEA offers me a way to see all events which can be implemented in a certain class.

Does such feature exist in Visual Studio?

The logic I am coding is non-UI and tools menu is empty.

Comment: What is the relation to unity3d?

Comment: Retagging since I think `Unity' is ment. Feel free to reroll if it's wrong.

Comment: @Joetjah, make sure you read the tag description before using it. The unity tag is for Microsoft Unity, which has nothing to do with this question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Visual Studio 2012 (I use Professional), will show intuitive options for a specific event, but not all options for a class. So it will be only within the sub or function and variable that you are using, it will throw up specific options.

I go to the .NET Framework Class Library to see all events.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg145045.aspx

Answer (score 2):

You can search for your library, namespace, and object type in the window that opens when you push CTRL + ALT + J.

Alternatively, you can create a variable of the type in question, place your cursor over the type, and press F12 or right-click and choose 'Go To Definition.'

Both methods open the same window, but the second one finds your type without you having to search.  You can right-click the right side of the window to filter or show member types, such as events, inherited members, etc.